# R: how to split list into AM/PM

Tags: r, filter, split

The time stamp on the survey grouped all of my data into one column under StartTime, but I need to split my data into AM and PM groups.

For example, right now my data looks like

```
8:37 PM
3:58 PM
10:22 AM
2:48 PM
6:33 PM
7:10 AM
10:59 AM
```

but I need to divide it into

```
8:37 PM  10:22 AM
3:58 PM  7:10 AM
2:48 PM 10:59 AM
6:33 PM
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`

```
split(df1, grepl('PM', df1$StartTime))
```

If you need to get a data.frame with two columns

```
 lst <- split(df1$StartTime, grepl('PM', df1$StartTime))
 setNames(data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))),
                   c('AM', 'PM'))
 #       AM      PM
 #1 10:22 AM 8:37 PM
 #2  7:10 AM 3:58 PM
 #3 10:59 AM 2:48 PM
 #4     <NA> 6:33 PM
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 dcast(setDT(df1)[, group:= c('AM', 'PM')[grepl('PM', StartTime)+1L]][,
           N:=1:.N, group], N~group, value.var='StartTime')
 #   N       AM      PM
 #1: 1 10:22 AM 8:37 PM
 #2: 2  7:10 AM 3:58 PM
 #3: 3 10:59 AM 2:48 PM
 #4: 4       NA 6:33 PM
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    extract(StartTime, into='AMPM', '[^ ]+\\s+([^ ]+)', remove=FALSE) %>%
    group_by(AMPM) %>%
    mutate(n=row_number()) %>% 
    spread(AMPM, StartTime)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(StartTime = c("8:37 PM", "3:58 PM", "10:22 AM", 
 "2:48 PM", "6:33 PM", "7:10 AM", "10:59 AM")), .Names = "StartTime",
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: I voted up, but they may be talking about the typo at `...max(lengths(lst...`

Comment: @plafort `lengths` is a new feature.  It is not a typo.

Comment: @plafort I am using `R 3.2.0`  It is similar to `max(sapply(lst, length))`, but very fast compared to that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`substring()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html), [`nchar()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nchar.html), [`within()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html), [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html), [`seq_along()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html), and [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html):

```
df <- data.frame(StartTime=c('8:37 PM','3:58 PM','10:22 AM','2:48 PM','6:33 PM','7:10 AM','10:59 AM'),stringsAsFactors=F);
reshape(within(df,{time<-substring(StartTime,nchar(StartTime)-1);id<-ave(time,time,FUN=seq_along);}),dir='w')[-1];
##   StartTime.PM StartTime.AM
## 1      8:37 PM     10:22 AM
## 2      3:58 PM      7:10 AM
## 4      2:48 PM     10:59 AM
## 5      6:33 PM         <NA>
```

This makes the assumption that the AM/PM substrings are always the final two characters of the input time strings.